# git branch --contains' issue

Tags: git, git-branch

On my remote repo I run git log --oneline -2 --all to find the last commits, I have an input related to commits with SHA1 and SHA2

but I run git branch --contains SHA(1/2), I have no output. Someone could explain ?

Comment: By 'remote repo' do you mean a bare repo? I tried out but `git branch --contains` seems to work fine even in a bare repo. Paste your exact commands and outputs?

Comment: No, no bare repo, when I run the git log command I find a classical : SHA1 Pushing the final version
SHA2 committing the added directory,

Comment: Can you provide the exact commands run and their outputs as a screenshot or in a pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

`git log -2` shows the current commit (aka HEAD) and its parent.
Those commits might be part of a branch but do not have to.

In your case it seems like HEAD points to a commit not contained in any branch.
It probably looks like this:

```
o-o-o-o master
   `o-o HEAD
```

You can check with `git branch`, which will list all local branches and indicate which branch you are on.
In your case it will probably say "no branch". (aka detached HEAD)

You can also try `git branch -r --contains HEAD` to check whether there might be a remote branch containing your commit.

A nice way to graphically find out what is going on is also `gitk`.

PS: You most probably don't work on your remote repository directly. You typically first clone it, and thereby creating a local repository, on which you work afterwards.

Comment: PPS: The hashing algorithm is called "SHA1". Talking about "SHA2" is a bit confusing. ;)